# How to convert varchar to int in CSV file?

Tags: sql, csv

I want to convert varchar data in CSV file to int. Unfortunately I keep getting the error as

> The multi-part identifier "xxx" could not be bound

I have tried following solutions:

```
SELECT CONVERT(int, [x].[data])
```

&

```
SELECT CAST([x].[data] as int)
```

[Sample data:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z8fbR.png)

Comment: Please add some actual data to your question.

Comment: ExcelRange objExcelRangeTotal = workSheet.Cells[rowRange];
objExcelRangeTotal.Style.Numberformat.Format = "#,##0.";

You can use number format while exporting data.

Comment: Include actual data sample of values that fails and include them as text, not images